# Appium Studio doesn't have latest Appium server

Tags: android, appium

For mobile automation I am start exploring Appium Studio. From Logs I found that latest Appium Studio doesn't have latest appium server.
I am using *Appium Studio V21.2.7916(2021-02-28)*, but in the console log it shows like appium version is *1.8.0* (Latest is *1.20.0*)

Console Log:

> ,"platformName":"Android","udid":"a0d6be2a","device.screenSize":"1080x2340","useKeystore":false,"test.type":"Mobile","commandTimeouts":"120000","appiumVersion":"1.8.0",

Do we have any configuration in Appium Studio to customize Appium Server, due to old Appium version. I ended up with many errors in Karate framework.

Appreciate for your support to resolve this issue

Comment: Not sure if this is related to `karate` or `appium`, may i suggest to check with `Appium Studio` support ? or use official latest version of appium-desktop from https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases

Answer (score 0):

You can point your execution to custom Appium server running on different port in AppiumStudio

[Custom Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzMtt.png)